# How to avoid code duplication from handling "structually similar types" in Scala?

Tags: scala, modeling, type-systems, data-modeling

Often, when programming, you'll have different degrees of information to you in different contexts.

For example, a web server may have two routes, which recieve information about a `Person`, one of these routes receives a Person with a `Name` and an id, and the other just receives a `Name`.

We want to write code that looks *something* like this, but probably more complicated:

```scala
def lookupPersonAge(person: Person): Int

// this doesn't receive a name
def route1(person: Person): Response = {
    complete(lookupPersonAge(person))
}

// this does receive a name
def route2(person: NamedPerson): Response = {
    complete(s"${person.name} is ${lookupPersonAge(person)} years old")
}
```

It's tempting to model `Person` as an interface, so that we can write generic code, that's usable between the two routes:

```scala
trait Person {
    def id: Int
}

case class PersonID(id: Int) extends Person

case class NamedPerson(id: Int, name: String) extends Person
```

The problem with this representation, is that if we want to write code against the generic `Person` interface, we loose a lot of useful things, such as pattern matching, and the auto generated copy method. 
This also looks confusingly similar to an Algebraic Data Type, despite the fact that it shouldn't be used like one.

Because of this, it's appealing to model `NamedPerson` using composition instead, for example

```scala
case class PersonId(id: Int)
case class NamedPerson(person: Person, name: String)
```

This is unwieldy, as it requires you to "lift" any methods written in  terms of `Person`, in order to apply them to `NamedPerson`, in this case, we'd have to write `route2` as:

```scala
def route2(person: NamedPerson): Response = {
    complete(s"${person.name} is ${lookupPersonAge(person.person)} years old")
}
```

It also scales poorly, as different combinations of fields are added, or if either type of `Person` may appear nested within another object.

For completeness, we could also model this using an `Option`:

```scala
case class Person(id: Int, name: Option[String])
```

This isn't appealing, because we do know whether or not the name is going to be present, we want to write code that's generic to whether or not it is.
And this representation would lead us to write the following code, which requires us to use an unsafe call to `get`

```scala
def route2(person: NamedPerson): Response = {
    complete(s"${person.name.get} is ${lookupPersonAge(person)} years old")
}
```

I feel like what I'm missing here is some form of structural typing, with that said, I'm sure I'm missing a nicer way to solve this kind of problem. 
What's an effective way to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is getting downvoted, which may be fair, but I'd be open to constructive feedback so I can improve the question?

Comment: i really wouldn’t take it personally. I’m not super active here, but I browse almost daily and almost every question gets downvoted—even those with 2-3 highly upvoted answers. I upvoted—I think it’s a fantastic question about strong, statically typed languages like scala. In a dynamic language like lisp, there are solutions that just aren’t available to you because you have to satisfy the type checker (which I still think is good thing!). Again, +1 here

Answer (score 1):

Scala does have structural types, but they incur a runtime penalty:

```scala
def lookupPersonAge(person: {val id: Int}): Int
```

There's also the typeclass route, but it requires more boilerplate to define the instances:

```scala
def lookupPersonAge[A](person: A)(implicit i: HasId[A]): Int
```

Another nice option in some situations is to make `Named` the trait:

```scala
trait Named {
    def name: String
}

case class Person(id: Int)

def route2(person: Person with Named): Response = {
    complete(s"${person.name} is ${lookupPersonAge(person)} years old")
}
```

This sort of generic programming is also what the [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library and related libraries like [henkan](https://github.com/kailuowang/henkan) are all about.

Those all have their uses and trade offs, but honestly, although I understand your question is simplified for illustration, in the vast majority of cases you're probably overthinking it. You're trying to codify a relationship between the types, when in reality, you just need to extract an `id`, which can be done with:

```scala
def lookupPersonAge(id: Int): Int
```

And called with:

```scala
def route1(person: Person): Response = {
    complete(lookupPersonAge(person.id))
}

def route2(person: NamedPerson): Response = {
    complete(s"${person.name} is ${lookupPersonAge(person.id)} years old")
}
```

Does `lookupPersonAge` really need features like pattern matching and copy methods, or does it just need the `id`? We don't want to artificially depend on things we don't need. So start simple and move to one of the more complex solutions if and when you actually need it. The simpler solutions also tend to be the most reusable.

You're suffering from choice here, which is a nice problem to have. No choice is going to be ideal in all situations.